# Bitnami Rubystack error : no version information available (required by nodejs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bitnami

I have a ruby stack (RubyStack-2.0.0-39) installed on Desktop Ubunutu 14:04.
I'm having trouble with it when I access my aplication view (http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in):

```html
JSON::ParserError - 757: unexpected token at 'nodejs: /opt/rubystack-2.0.0-39/common/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by nodejs)
nodejs: /opt/rubystack-2.0.0-39/common/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by nodejs)
nodejs: /opt/rubystack-2.0.0-39/common/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by nodejs)
["ok"]':
json (1.8.3) lib/json/common.rb:155:in parse'
execjs (2.6.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:68:inextract_result'
execjs (2.6.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in exec'
execjs (2.6.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:14:ininitialize'
execjs (2.6.0) lib/execjs/runtime.rb:44:in compile'
execjs (2.6.0) lib/execjs/module.rb:27:incompile'
coffee-script (2.4.1) lib/coffee_script.rb:50:in context'
coffee-script (2.4.1) lib/coffee_script.rb:78:incompile'
sprockets (3.3.4) lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:21:in block in call'
sprockets (3.3.4) lib/sprockets/cache.rb:85:infetch'
sprockets (3.3.4) lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:20:in call'
sprockets (3.3.4) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:incall_processor'
sprockets (3.3.4) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.3.4) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:incall_processors'
sprockets (3.3.4) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.3.4) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:inblock in load'....
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Open ubuntu softer center 
2) Click on installed software 
3) Search "node" keyword in search bar 
4) Remove all node plugins

I had installed another version of the node after it removes the ruby stack returned to work.